# tkinter: moving the center of text in a widget

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program I can create Buttons containing text. The x-buttons are there to get rid of the blue button that it's on and the x-button itself. As you can see below the text is centered exactly in the center of the blue button which makes the space between the left edge and the right egde (up until the x-button) unproportional and also longer texts do not fit in. Anchoring the text to the left makes it look ugly. Is there a way to move the center of the text a bit to the left so that it looks like in the second image?

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

active_color = "#00FFFF"
inactive_color = "#99FFFF"

students = []

class StudentButton(Button):
    # same as a tkinter.Button but you can change the color
    # do activate/inactivate the student

    def switch_activity(self):
        # switches color of the student_button
        # ...

def remove_student(student):
    # removes a student button and its x-button passed into this function
    # ...
    pass

def add_student():
    new_student = student_entry.get()
    students.append(new_student)

    i = (len(students) - 1) // 6
    j = (len(students) - 1) % 6
    place_student(i, j, new_student)

def place_student(i, j, new_student): # places student accordingly to how much there are in 'students' list
    canvas = Canvas(main_frame, borderwidth=5)
    canvas.place(relx=j / 6, rely=i / 5, relwidth=1 / 6, relheight=1 / 5)

    student_button = StudentButton(canvas, text=new_student, borderwidth=5, bg=active_color, font=font.Font(size=12),
                            command=lambda: student_button.switch_activity())
    student_button.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)


    student_delete_button = Button(canvas, command=lambda: remove_student(new_student), borderwidth=0, image=img_xbutton)
    student_delete_button.place(relx=0.95, rely=0.5, anchor=E)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1080x800")


main_frame = Frame(root, bg="#FFFFCC")
main_frame.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.35)

student_entry = Entry(root)
student_entry.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.03, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.05)

student_add_button = Button(root, text="add", font=font.Font(size=12), command=add_student)
student_add_button.place(relx=0.22, rely=0.03, relwidth=0.08, relheight= 0.05 )

img_xbutton = PhotoImage(file='xbutton.png')

root.mainloop()
```

That's as little code as I could use to reproduce a simplified creation of those buttons.
Also because someone asked in comments: the red button is to get completeley rid of the student_button and the x-button on top of it. The blue student_button itself has the function of changing color. Anyway I just need to know how to slightly move the center of text (preferably without using spaces :) )

Comment: If you want a specific solution, then please provide a minimal reproducible example. Otherwise I would say yes it is possible to provide what you are asking. A very easy way would just be adding some spaces to align the text, but of course that is not generalised. But I have to ask why you are adding the [X] picture to your button like this? It will look to the user like you can only click on the [X] while you in fact can click anywhere on the button.

Comment: Please show how you are creating these buttons by [edit]ing your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you're creating the button, I would say the simplest thing to do is use the button's `compound` feature to put an invisible image to the right of the text. The invisible image will serve as padding for the text.

In the following example I create a button that has a 50 pixel image to the right of the text, effectively moving the text to the left by 50 pixels.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Hello, world")
b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Hello, world")

b1.configure(image=tk.PhotoImage(width=50, height=1), compound="right")

b1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
b2.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Notice that both widgets have the same text, but the second button has the text offset by 50 pixels.

[image: screenshot]